# Angular: Pass objects in directive and check if they are true as flags

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to pass objects through directive as flags and enable/disable them.

```
  <my-directive flags="{button: true, banner: false}"></my-directive>
```

Inside of the directive HTML:

```
<div ng-show="{button==='true'}" >
  Button
</div>
<div ng-show="{banner==='true'}" >
  Banner
</div>
```

Directive JS:

```
module.exports = directive;
function directive(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'directive.html',
    scope: {
      flags: '='
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove extra " from <my-directive>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access using `flags.button`

Working Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/RDKaWleE2KlYOttoqKi4?p=preview
Check `directive.html` in Plunker

E.g.

```
Directive:
<div ng-show="flags.button === true" >
  Button
</div>
<div ng-show="flags.banner === true" >
  Banner
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `flag` as this:

```
<div ng-show="flags.button===true" >
  Button
</div>
<div ng-show="flags.banner===true" >
  Banner
</div>
```

Triple equation (===) checks for type equality besides value equality.

Answer (score 0):

Use `flags` object as you defined it in `scope`. And you don't need brackets at all.

```
<div ng-show="flags.button" >
  Button
</div>
<div ng-show="flags.banner" >
  Banner
</div>
```